# Why the image of the website can't load while below ios14?

Tags: html, css

Here is my website:https://www.sealintelligence.com/en/thermal_inkjet.html
[image]

[image]

All image works well on ios 14 while can not load any when below ios 14.(just like the image above)

In spite of ios support the WEBP format until ios 14, I have used a picture element to try to solve this.

```
<picture>
        <source srcset="/images/CommercialProducts/thermal_inkjet/BG.webp">
        <img src="/images/CommercialProducts/thermal_inkjet/BG.png">
</picture>
```

However, it seems the PNG format doesn't work any.

What's the problem and how can I solve this? Thank you.

Comment: Are you saying it works on IOS 14 but not below? caniuse.com give status on IOS 13 and below as unknown (for source element).

Comment: @AHaworth However, all the background-image doesn't work also. It doesn't base on the source element.

Comment: So, does the img work 1. by itself 2. when within a picture element?

Comment: @AHaworth I just made 3 test:1. IMG works only with itself 2.IMG works when the picture element contains it only. 3.Base on the second test, I tried to remove all the sources in the picture element by JQUERY but the image still can not load.

Comment: @AHaworth I tried some polyfill for picture such as https://github.com/verlok/picturePolyfill and it doesn't work also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a stupid way to solve this:
The img element works while there is no source element inside the picture element.

So remove all source elements while below ios14 by Jquery.

```
$("source").remove();
```

Answer (score -1):

try changing your  file format from PNG to JPG. When I did a image file link from a jpg image, it works. It may have something to do with the fact that you are using an PNG image.

Comment: I tried to make a sample page by adding only an IMG element to render the same PNG file, and now it works.